# Is this integration possible?

Tags: integration, geometry, vectors

I was trying to derive the perimeter of a circle using vector algebra and came across this.....

Taking a circle of radius $r$ with center at the origin, the position vector of a particular point on the circle making an angle $t$ with the positive x-axis is given by, $$\vec r_o = r\cos t \hat i + r\sin t \hat j  $$
If we move this point so by an infinitesimally small amount such that the new position vector of the point subtends an angle of $t+dt$ with the positive x-axis, then the new position vector is given by $$\vec r = r\cos (t+dt)\hat i + r\sin (t +dt)\hat j$$
The small displacement vector $dl$ will be given by, $$\vec {dl} = \vec r - \vec r_o$$
After substitution you get, $$\vec {dl} = r [\cos (t+dt)-\cos t ]\hat i + r[\sin(t+dt)-\sin t]\hat j$$
The magnitude of this infinitesimal displacement would be, $$||\vec {dl}|| = dl = \sqrt {{r^2 [\cos (t+dt)-\cos t ]}^2+{r^2[\sin(t+dt)-\sin t]^2}}$$
After further simplification; $$dl = 2r\sin {\frac{dt}{2}}$$
To get the arclength (say, $da$); $$da = dl = 2r\sin{\frac{dt}{2}}$$
Usually we approximate $\sin{dt}=dt$ as $dt\to0$ and we end up with $$dl = 2r \frac{dt}{2} = rdt$$
and integrate this equation to get the perimeter of the circle, instead i tried applying the taylor expansion of $\sin$ $$\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+ ....$$
$$dl = 2r[\frac{dt}{2}-\frac{(\frac{dt}{2})^3}{3!}+\frac{(\frac{dt}{2})^5}{5!}-\frac{(\frac{dt}{2})^7}{7!}+....]$$
Integrating the above, $$\int{dl}=2r[\int{\frac{dt}{2}}-\int{\frac{(\frac{dt}{2})^3}{3!}}+\int{\frac{(\frac{dt}{2})^5}{5!}}-\int{\frac{(\frac{dt}{2})^7}{7!}}+....]$$I'm stuck at this point and don't know how to carry forward, so i need some help....

Comment: It's a bit of a circular (pun intended) endeavor. The functions $\sin$ and $\cos$ already contain information about circles in them, so using them to derive properties about circles is putting the cart before the horse, so to speak.

Comment: Talk about mixed metaphors!

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be yes and no.

Since $dt$ is not a number, terms like $\sin (t+dt)$ or $\cos (dt)$ are meaningless. In fact, this is the reason why we need Taylor's theorem: for small $ t>0$, there exist $0 \le c \le  t$ such that $f(x+ t) = f(x) + f'(x)t + f''(x)t^2/2 + \dots + f^{(k)}(x) t^k/k! + f^{(k+1)}(x + c) t^{k+1}/(k+1)!$.

Try to show $\|\mathbf{r}(t+\Delta t) - \mathbf{r}(t)\|= \sqrt{1 + c \Delta t}\cdot \Delta t$, where $c$ term can be bounded by finite number. (My calculation gives $c \le 1.5$, but I'm not sure if my calculation is correct.) So, when taking $\Delta t \to 0$ limit, $\|d \vec{l}\|/dt =1$, so the integration for the perimeter is value $2\pi$ when the radius is $1$.

Taylor's theorem is important because not only it gives good power series expression, but also it gives a remainder part which we can control and bound.

I've heard that the infinitesimals can be thought as notion in [dual number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number). In this sense, $(dt)^2$ and higher powers are vanishing. (This doesn't prove anything, but it gives a possible way to interpret.) I don't suggest you to build your calculus ideas on such things; following the real analytic path is a better idea to learn things.

Comment: The vectorheads are off their place. In texts, conventionally we use $\textbf{boldface}$ to denote vectors.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be clearer to define the equations parametrically, which is really just splitting up vectors. This gives you:
$$x=r\cos t\\y=r\sin t$$
now:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-r\sin t\\\frac{dy}{dt}=r\cos t$$
now remember that to get the circumference we want to integrate over the path, which would be:
$$\int\limits_Cdl$$
now use the fact that this $dl$ segment can be represented as:
$$dl=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2}dt$$
where $C$ can be represented parametrically as $t\in[0,2\pi)$

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I don't understand what's wrong with my approach....

Comment: the notation is quite confusing, saying $\lim_{dt\to0}\int dt$ doesn't make sense as an integration variable is just that, variable. It is already a given that it tends to zero as that is partly the definition of a differential. I would consider using small angle approximations here, as they are very accurate, and in this case $\sin(dt)=dt$ is-in fact- true